# Change Display Color Of Wireframe object

Tags: 3d-view, color

I made an object to act as an empty for the movement of my character.  I changed its display to wire frame, and I would also like to change the viewport color of the wire frame object to something like blue.  Is there a way I can do this without changing the color of every single wire frame object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it in Preferences > Themes > 3D Viewport > Wire

[image: Wire]

Comment: This answer works for me!  Question, is there a way to have it so some wireframe objects are colored differently than others?

Comment: I don't think so, at least not by traditional means. If anyone else knows differently, feel free to correct me.

Comment: k thanks for your help!